# Create shortcut to .pyw file from within python

Tags: python, windows, shortcut, pywin32

I was wondering how to create a shortcut in python to .pyw extensions and .exe's.

Comment: What do you mean by a shortcut? Do you want to run a .exe from a Python script?

Comment: @Rafe: A .lnk file, like Explorer uses.

Comment: hey rafe what i meant was like on my desktop all of those are shortcuts. im making my own installer or more like extracter and i want to code something that will do the same as last clicking on my .pyw file copying it, and pasting pasting the shortcut on desktop. ignacio seems to have the answer thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought you wanted to do something else

Answer (score 2):

You need to create and use a [IShellLink](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-a-shortcut.html) via COM.

Comment: ok one last thing i know this should be asked as a seperate question but its so related i might aswell ask it here. how do i change the icon once i've made this shortcut. thanks it works by the way

Comment: Probably via the `SetIconLocation()` method.